# facing issue in preg_replace()

Tags: regex, php-5.3

I wan to replace `"hello world."` and any character after that with `"hi" from "this is nice place. <br> hello world.<br>thanks and regards"` with use of `preg_replace()`

code is like that

```
$arr1 = array('/hello world./');
$arr2 = array('hi');
$str = "this is nice place. <br> hello world.<br>thanks and regards.";
echo preg_replace($arr1, $arr2, $str);
```

but with this i am not only able to replace "hello world." from  $str. But I want regular expression to replace all characters after "hello world." also.

Comment: So... what's the question? Your code (kinda) works.

Comment: but with this i am not only able to replace "hello world." from $str. But I want regular expression to replace all characters after "hello world." also.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = array('/hello world\..*$/');
$arr2 = array('hi');
$str = "this is nice place. <br> hello world.<br>thanks and regards.";
echo preg_replace($arr1, $arr2, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array('/hello world\..*$/');
```

The first dot is escaped by `\` because otherwise it's an operator meaning "any character". The following is "any character" (`.`) any number of times (`*`) followed by the end of the string (`$`).